# Which files should I configure to STOP AUTO-CONVERTING input method(keyboard layout) whenever I open bash shell?

Tags: bash, input, keyboard

I am Korean. So I have two keyboard layouts, KR / EN.

There is a problem. **I can't input Korean on bash shell.** It is fine with output. I can read KR on bash, e.g file names.

Same thing happen while I am coding in vim editor(actually it is the neovim). Fine output, bad input.

I have tried hundred times to solve it. But I got just a single micro clue.
There is a icon showing which input method and which language I am using. I found out whenever I open terminal, that icon changes from one thing to another. If I come back to a browser or anything other than terminal, the icon turns back as well.

Here is my system info.

```
██████████████████  ████████   sy@sy-81f4 
██████████████████  ████████   ---------- 
██████████████████  ████████   OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64 
██████████████████  ████████   Host: 81F4 Lenovo ideapad 330S-14IKB 
████████            ████████   Kernel: 5.10.157-1-MANJARO 
████████  ████████  ████████   Uptime: 51 mins 
████████  ████████  ████████   Packages: 1241 (pacman) 
████████  ████████  ████████   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
████████  ████████  ████████   Resolution: 1920x1080 
████████  ████████  ████████   WM: i3 
████████  ████████  ████████   Theme: Adapta-Nokto-Eta-Maia [GTK2/3] 
████████  ████████  ████████   Icons: Papirus-Adapta-Nokto-Maia [GTK2/3] 
████████  ████████  ████████   Terminal: urxvt 
████████  ████████  ████████   Terminal Font: D2Coding 
                               CPU: Intel i5-8250U (8) @ 3.400GHz 
                               GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
                               Memory: 4069MiB / 11882MiB
```

I apologize my poor English. Thanks for your lovely effort reading it.

I have tried to configure these files.

- something like .vimrc for the neovim
- something for i3 config
- something for .bashrc
- something named like 'inputrc'

and locale at /etc/environment

Comment: you should ask this question on the unix and linux exchange here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is unrlated to bash, but most likely related to your OS (Linux), the Terminal (urxvt) and perhaps the Window Manager (which you don't mention). I feel that your "clue" is right: The problem is related to how the UI associates an input method to a window.

Comment: Ah, sorry, just notice that you do mention the Window Manager (i3). With this information, you should be able to get help at unix.stackexchange.com or [su]. Make sure that you tag your question properly (_input-method_, _i3_).